# Create an enterprise geodatabase - Administrator username and password are required

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to create an enterprise geodatabase in oracle 11g, using the create enterprise geodatabase tool  in arcmap 10.2.
I have properly installed the oracle client needed and I am able to create a database connection (both as sys and system users).

However, when I am trying to execute the tool create enterprise geodatabase, it fails. 
I asks for administrator username and password as shown in the image.

[image]
[image]

Any ideas about how this could be resolved or debugged ?

Comment: You might try going to menu Geoprocessing -> Results. Might give you a bit more details. Also, don't use Oracle :p. Seems like ArcGIS.com themselves have moved to PostgreSQL!

Comment: If I could, maybe I would :) However the dbms of our system, which already contains  non spatial information is in Oracle. As a result I would like to use some of the existing tables containing spatial information as well as non spatial info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was not completing the geodatabase administrator field since it says that it is optional. When I provided one, it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the sys password of that Oracle instance in order to run the create enterprise geodatabase. If you have another user with dba privileges you can run this to change the password:

alter user sys identified by NEWPASSWORD;

If you have a database administrator in your organization, they should have the sys password.

Optionally, if you have an Oracle database created you can run the enable enterprise geodatabase tool to create the SDE system tables.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000162000000

Comment: Indeed, Enable Enterprise Geodatabase can be used as a replacement for Create Enterprise Geodatabase,  *IF* you issue the necessary PUBLIC grants and create the SDE tablespace and SDE user beforehand.

Comment: The fact is that I am using an oracleXE so as to have administrator rights. However using the sys password I have set on my own has no results.